# I am having vs I have

Tags: tense, present-continuous, present-simple

I'm finally learning English grammar, and I'm having an issue with understanding the difference between:

> - Now I **have** much more fun learning English than I had before the course.

and

> - Now I **am having** much more fun learning English than I had before the course.

Is there one? Supposedly the correct answer is the former one, but I think that the latter is also correct.

If it helps, I'm solving the Grammar Test from this website:

https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/tests/language-course

Answer (score 2):

The former is more traditionally and grammatically-correct.

The latter is a statement that reflects a 1980's-forward-to-present day evolution of the same sentiment, but in a conversational fashion.

The differences are fine, but it is safe to say that a young person using the former statement expresses a genuine satisfaction at learning English, and the same young person using the latter expresses a gushing, emphatic ebullience about learning English.

Answer (score 0):

> "Now I **have** much more fun learning English than I had before the course."

Compares to:

> 'I do have fun when I am there (e.g. in the class)'.

The fun occurs when you are actually doing it.

This is specific and compartmentalized.

> "Now I **am having** much more fun learning English than I had before the course."

Compares to:

> 'I am currently (ongoing/right now) having more fun'.

The fun occurs randomly whether you are actively learning or not at that moment.  This is broader and overall.